# Membership details search, view, edit by staff in frontend

Tags: civimember

I am trying to build membership system for a table tennis business store. Owner want to store his members info with civicrm. He dont want to use online membership sign up system now. His staff will add members info and assign members to various membership manually.

Staff wont have access to backend. So staff need to have frontend feature so they can search, view, add, edit, update, delete members membership.

Its easy to do that in backend. But I can not figure out how to have this membership features in frontend.

So wondering, is this possible what I am looking?

I am using joomla.

Thanks
Julash